# iPhone: How does a UIView object know which is its Controller?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

The responder chain sends an event to a view and then to its controller. But how does the system know the controller object for the view ? I didn't find any property in UIView that stores the reference to its controller. On the other hand, a controller clearly has the view property to identify its view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView` (`UIResponder` subclass) knows about it's viewcontroller or superview through the instance method

`- (UIResponder *)nextResponder`

From `UIResponder` class reference:

> The UIResponder class does not store
>   or set the next responder
>   automatically, instead returning nil
>   by default. Subclasses must override
>   this method to set the next responder.
>   UIView implements this method by
>   returning the UIViewController object
>   that manages it (if it has one) or its
>   superview (if it doesn’t);
>   UIViewController implements the method
>   by returning its view’s superview;
>   UIWindow returns the application
>   object, and UIApplication returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, ViewController is the first object for system (not the UIView), it is included in responder chain (read about UIResponder class), and manages touches, sending them to corresponding UIView's.

Comment: nope. read again. UIView -> its ViewController -> UIView's superView.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation how the responder chain works: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/bit-about-responder-chain.html .

EDIT:

Because view controllers are tightly bound to the views they manage, they are also part of the responder chain used to handle events. View controllers are themselves descendants of the UIResponder class and are inserted into the responder chain between the managed view and its superview.

So the UIView and UIViewControllers as well are descendants of UIResponder, which has a setNextResponder: method to keep track of the next responder in the chain.

Moszi